# Trying to publish to my test registry (Verdaccio) but instead being pushed to my Company Registry

Tags: e2e-testing, e2e, verdaccio

After the Verdaccio server starts on port 4000, I try to publish to my local registry by running

```
npm publish --access=public --json --registry http://localhost:4000 --json
```

I get the following error that confirms its attempting to publish a version that exists in my companies registry instead of publishing to localhost:4000

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOeCX.png)

I do have my companies registry data in the npmrc. Once I remove it from the npmrc, the package is successfully published to my local Verdaccio server. I was looking in Verdaccio's documentation but didn't find anything. Are there any thing I can do to bypass the npmrc without removing my companies registry information?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVSG8.png)

Publish my package to localhost:4000 instead of my company registry